# Set up minikube installation with gke

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, minikube

I just want to set up minikube on kubernetes

While installing facing an error

```
Minikube start--kubernetes-version=vm-driver="hyperv'--hyperv-virtual-switch=minikube
```

I want to resolve above error

I want to know the limitations of minikube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error could be the result of an outdated Minikube cache. My suggestion to you is to start over by removing the minikube installation and its cache.

**Follow below troubleshooting steps to resolve the issue**

**1)** Run `minikube delete --all` --purge to remove the extra config files

**2)** Remove the.minikube and  cache folders

```
cd C:\\Users\\user\_name.minikube\\ Remove-Item –path C:\\Users\\user\_name.minikube\\cache\* -recurse
```

The above command will help you to  clean up the existing cache of your minikube.

Alternatively, you could try removing all.files of minikube

```
Remove-Item –path C:\\Users\\user\_name.minikube\* -recurse -force
```

**3)** Now start minikube.

Mostly it will work now

**Limitations of minikube**:

The fact that Minikube can only have one node in the local cluster is one of its main drawbacks. Therefore, it might not be the ideal tool for emulating or testing larger Kubernetes clusters with numerous nodes, which are more similar to real-world production settings.

Follow this official [document](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/shell/minikube-local-development#:%7E:text=a%20minikube%20cluster-,Cloud%20Code%20automatically%20installs%20and%20manages%20minikube.,Cloud%20Code%3A%20Control%20minikub) to install minikube on gcp

Refer this  [blog](https://sensu.io/blog/minikube-tutorial)  by Jef Spaleta to install minikube on kubernetes